# script not run after reboot from /etc/rc3.d

Tags: linux, bash, solaris, symbolic-link

I create symbolic  link to the file - /etc/rc3.d/platform.bash from /var/tmp/platform.bash

```
      ln -s  /var/tmp/platform.bash   /etc/rc3.d/platform.bash
```

script exist under /var/tmp :

```
      -rwxr-xr-x   1 root     root       58442 Aug 30 08:49 platform.bash
```

view from /etc/rc3.d :

```
          lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     root          31 Aug 30 06:33 S99platform.bash -> /var/tmp/platform.bash
```

my target is to run platform.bash after reboot ( on solaris 10 OS )

from some reason the script platform.bash not run after reboot ?
please advice what I need to check in order to verify the problem ?

my script ( platform.bash )

```
      #!/bin/bash


      echo test > /var/tmp/log.txt
```

Comment: How did you know it is not executed? Is it writing to some log file/updating some other file, etc..?

Comment: yes its write to log.txt but log not activated ! ( log is empty)

Comment: I'm not familiar with Solaris but could you please post `platform.bash`?

Comment: see my update - its example - log.txt must have the string test but after reboot test string not in the file log.txt

Answer (score 1):

Thats not the right way to start the scripts. Your script should have its appropriate S##/K## with it.
For example, you should make link as `

> /etc/rc3.d/S98platform.bash

` and

> `/etc/rc3.d/K98platform.bash`

as every script runs with its appropriate START and KILL script in a numerical order.

You should follow this artticle tobetter understand the Solaris init scripts process:

http://www.techrepublic.com/article/get-it-done-start-and-stop-applications-automatically-using-solaris-scripts/5034999

Comment: not clear for me why - S99platform.bash ( not the right way ) as you know the script S99platform.bash  (S99) will start at the end of the boot what bad with S99 ??? , this is according init rules !